# Stopping Visual Studio from displaying error list when there are just warnings during file edit

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

Is there a way to stop Visual Studio 2012 from popping up the Error List when there are only warnings? I am writing a .resx file for localization of my sitemap and every time I put .title in my Resource's Name column it generates a warning which then pops up the stupid error list. Is there a way from stopping this stupid list from popping up on only warnings during normal editing of a file. I have tried turning off the Tools -> Options -> Projects and Solutions -> General -> Always show Error List if Build finishes with errors. I have even set the build output to quite but that does not affect it either since these only affect builds and I am just editing not building.

Comment: The warning is the same in the file so if I could just suppress that one warning that would be fine, but I don't know how to do that either.

Answer (score 2):

I suspect you're referring to IntelliSense errors, not compiler warnings. If so, right-click on the error list column header and uncheck "Show IntelliSense Errors".